# Selecting a random image

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get a random image to show up on load. This is the code I'm using:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ImageArray = new Array();
    image[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
    image[1] = 'kitchen4.jpg';
    image[2] = 'pig1.jpg';
    image[3] = 'site1.jpg';
    image[4] = 'site2.jpg';
    image[5] = 'site3.jpg';
    image[6] = 'site4.jpg';
    image[7] = 'site5.jpg';
    image[8] = 'site6.jpg';
    image[9] = 'site7.jpg';
    image[10] = 'site8.jpg';


function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").textContent = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getRandomImage()">
<div id="randImage"></div>
</body>
```

I'm new to javascript, and cobbled this together from snippets I found on line.

The problem with this code is that it shows `<img src="images/random/undefined" width="250px">`, instead of an image.

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21976204/3315914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageArray` has no items, so getting any index of it will return undefined.  I think you are trying to set values of `ImageArray`, but accidentally put `image`.  Second, you don't want `textContent`, you want `innerHTML`.  This is probably the code you meant to have:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ImageArray = new Array();
    ImageArray[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
    ImageArray[1] = 'kitchen4.jpg';
    ImageArray[2] = 'pig1.jpg';
    ImageArray[3] = 'site1.jpg';
    ImageArray[4] = 'site2.jpg';
    ImageArray[5] = 'site3.jpg';
    ImageArray[6] = 'site4.jpg';
    ImageArray[7] = 'site5.jpg';
    ImageArray[8] = 'site6.jpg';
    ImageArray[9] = 'site7.jpg';
    ImageArray[10] = 'site8.jpg';


function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").innerHTML = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getRandomImage()">
<div id="randImage"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: And second he will have to use innerHTML instead of textContent.

Comment: @wumm `textContent` works fine, doesn't it? It's like using jQuery's `.text()` instead of `.html()` - it works too, but `textContent` works for both HTML and XML files, while `innerHTML` only works for HTML.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Exactly, but the OP is trying to reach "random image to show up on load" I don't think he wants to display HTML code.

Comment: @wumm Oh, I thought it had to do with entities for that.  Well, answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the array and change `textContent` to `innerHTML` ... [SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yupur/2/edit)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ImageArray = new Array();
    ImageArray[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
    ImageArray[1] = 'kitchen4.jpg';
    ImageArray[2] = 'pig1.jpg';
    ImageArray[3] = 'site1.jpg';
    ImageArray[4] = 'site2.jpg';
    ImageArray[5] = 'site3.jpg';
    ImageArray[6] = 'site4.jpg';
    ImageArray[7] = 'site5.jpg';
    ImageArray[8] = 'site6.jpg';
    ImageArray[9] = 'site7.jpg';
    ImageArray[10] = 'site8.jpg';


function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").innerHTML = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not assigning the values of the array `ImageArray`, but the array `image`. You can change this by either renaming your image array to `image`, or the other way around. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image = new Array();
    image[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
    image[1] = 'kitchen4.jpg';
    image[2] = 'pig1.jpg';
    image[3] = 'site1.jpg';
    image[4] = 'site2.jpg';
    image[5] = 'site3.jpg';
    image[6] = 'site4.jpg';
    image[7] = 'site5.jpg';
    image[8] = 'site6.jpg';
    image[9] = 'site7.jpg';
    image[10] = 'site8.jpg';


    function getRandomImage() {
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
        var img = image[num];
        document.getElementById("randImage").textContent = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

    }
</script>
```

OR:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ImageArray = new Array();
    ImageArray[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
    ImageArray[1] = 'kitchen4.jpg';
    ImageArray[2] = 'pig1.jpg';
    ImageArray[3] = 'site1.jpg';
    ImageArray[4] = 'site2.jpg';
    ImageArray[5] = 'site3.jpg';
    ImageArray[6] = 'site4.jpg';
    ImageArray[7] = 'site5.jpg';
    ImageArray[8] = 'site6.jpg';
    ImageArray[9] = 'site7.jpg';
    ImageArray[10] = 'site8.jpg';


    function getRandomImage() {
        var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
        var img = ImageArray[num];
        document.getElementById("randImage").textContent = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

    }
</script>
```

The name of the variable you store your image names in needs to be consistent throughout the script.

Answer (score 0):

You should defined `image` an array but `ImageArray`, you can also reduce the code something like this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var image = ['goat1.jpg', 'kitchen4.jpg', 'pig1.jpg', 
    'site1.jpg', 'site2.jpg', 'site3.jpg', 'site4.jpg', 'site5.jpg', 
    'site6.jpg', 'site7.jpg', 'site8.jpg']; 

function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);

    var img = image[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").textContent = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getRandomImage()">
<div id="randImage"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ImageArray` when assigning elements of the array:

```
ImageArray[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
```

instead of:

```
image[0] = 'goat1.jpg';
```

I would also recommend assigning the array at its declaration instead of using individual statements to assign values to different elements of the array:

```
var ImageArray = ['goat1.jpg','kitchen4.jpg','pig1.jpg','site1.jpg','site2.jpg','site3.jpg','site4.jpg','site5.jpg','site6.jpg','site7.jpg','site8.jpg'];

function getRandomImage() {
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);
    var img = ImageArray[num];
    document.getElementById("randImage").innerHTML = ('<img src="' + 'images/random/' + img + '" width="250px">')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for changes:

```
var imgs = ['goat1.jpg','kitchen4.jpg','pig1.jpg','site1.jpg','site2.jpg',
            'site3.jpg','site4.jpg','site5.jpg','site6.jpg','site7.jpg',
            'site8.jpg'];
function getRandomImage(){
 var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length);
 document.getElementById('randImage').src = imgs[rnd];
}
...
<div><img id="randImage" /></div>
```